# Индексация чисел введённых пользователем в Python

Tags: python-3.x

Пользователь вводит трехзначное число, первую и последнюю цифру которого нужно сравнивать. Но к сожалению индексы не работают с числами. Подскажите, какой есть выход?

Comment: Деление и остаток от деления используйте.

Comment: как вы читаете числа от пользователя. Покажите конкретный код (только ту часть, которая числа читает)—отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте туда этот код, нажмите [edit]. Вы должны получить строку (в которой индексы работают)

Answer (score 0):

Первую цифру числа получаем делением нацело на 100, последнюю - взятием остатка от деления на 10. Результаты сравниваем между собой.